# Why does my HTML email signature appear cut-off in Outlook?

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

It's been about two years since I worked with HTML code... I followed the instructions on how to do this from https://blog.gimm.io/how-to-create-an-html-email-signature/

I built/ edited the code with webstorm. this layout looks perfect when I test opened the code in chrome... but what it looked like when I copy and pasted into outlook as a disclaimer, it shows up in received emails like it turned into a non downloadable image with a tiny single line of text. (outlooks instructions on how to add the signature from the admin portal, which i have to do it this way for multiple people.) it seems I can only attach 1 image, so it's of the admin portal rule. and the page is not letting me enter the code sample at the moment. *grumble*

What am I missing to make this work correctly?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Your New Email Signature!</title>
        <style>a{text-decoration: none}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="zs-output-sig" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:0px;font-size:1px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;margin:0px;border-collapse:collapse; width:500px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:0px;font-size:1px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;margin:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:0px;font-size:1px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;margin:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:0px;font-size:1px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;margin:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:0px;font-size:1px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;margin:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14.0px;font-style:normal;line-height:16px;font-weight:normal;color:#414141;"><span style="font-family:Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14.0px;font-style:normal;line-height:16px;font-weight:normal;color:#414141; display:inline;">Regards,</span></td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td style="border-collapse:collapse;padding-bottom:10px;height:10px;"></td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:0px;font-size:1px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;margin:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="152">
                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:0px;font-size:1px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;margin:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
```

Comment: How does your HTML look like? Could you be more specific?

Comment: no idea if this will work as a work around but worth a try. http://localhost:63342/anthony-bussell/kim%20novotny.html?_ijt=2clden1s1mheb9nh1o1r135fsr

Comment: I keep getting this error when i try to add my code to this post: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Have you tried all these pointers? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow

I think also you can do a blcok by using the backtick button three times, copying the code, then pressing another three backticks (tilde key typically next to number 1): `

Comment: What is this, a SharePoint page? Why do you have a thousand tables nested in each other when only the last descendant has content? Delete all those extra wrapping tables and save yourself some pain.

Comment: Also, writing the HTML code in a proper editor (with indentation) will help make it clear if your code is getting truncated. As you can see from my edit, the code you included in your comments (when properly formatted/indented) is clearly cut off prematurely before all the tables and trs, etc., are closed.

Comment: Thank you Tyler! I did cut out a lot of the "fluff" and got part of the code to work on outlook. still having a character cutoff issue.

Comment: Thank you Nathan! I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't display base64 images and may block any web images by default. If you need to use images the best solution is to embed an image by attaching it to the email item and then referring to such images by using a special notation using the `cid:` prefix.

```
mail.Attachments.Add "D:\ImageFile.img", olByValue, 0
sImgName = "ImageFile.img" 
mail.HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:" & sImgName & "'" & " ><br>" 'Mention only the image file name not its path
```

The fact is that Outlook uses Word as a rendering engine. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Outlook has a character cutoff! My code was getting broken before the code itself got to any visible content. According to a Microsoft representative, Microsoft made it so that only approved 3rd parties (that you have to pay for) can create nice email signatures.

Comment: Did the representative mention what the character count is for you? Or how the 3rd parties are able to do this and you aren't (e.g. do _they_ pay a licensing fee to Microsoft for access to some API or token of some kind)?

Comment: the guy i talked to was a bit clueless and had to keep calling me back after he talked with his manager. the only thing that he could say was that i was to look up a local third party vendor to apply my code. when I questioned him if it was a licensing issue, he expressed relief that i "understood" why i could not implement the code on my own. he apologized several times for having his "hands tied" on the subject.

Comment: Hmm, bummer. I would have recommended you request the ticket be escalated if it were still open, so that you can understand _why_ the requirement is in place and how the 3rd party vendor has that capability. While Microsoft partners do have a lot of elevated access, someone at MSFT should at least be able to _tell_ you that in clear terms.

Comment: I did refuse to close the ticket twice and requested escalation. what i was told is that Microsoft refused to deal with custom code. hence they pass it off to a third party. I was under the impression that those licensed third parties could keep custom code from breaking or Trojaning the Microsoft suite programs so Microsoft can keep it's products secure and stable. which makes understandable sense to me from a business/product and liability perspective.

Comment: Sorry to hear you didn't have any luck with them... that's unfortunately the case so often with Microsoft. Maybe if you are able to find a good 3rd party vendor of this nature, _they_ would be willing to explain a bit about how they're able to do what you as a (4th party?) cannot.